# No photo album sharing like DropBox in Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online photo gallery for Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19251/online-photo-gallery-for-ubuntu-one)

I would really like to be able to settle on Ubuntu One, but I can't find a way to share pictures/photos like I can with DropBox. DropBox has a "photos" folder where I can put up pictures and a link to share those pictures as a shared gallery can be created from right clicking on the folder in Nautilus. Is there a way to share pictures, or are they simply treated like any other files in Ubuntu One. If the latter is the case consider this a feature request.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, this is a Q+A site not a bug tracker. However you can file your feature request here and the U1 team will be notified, thanks! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone/+filebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what I do for now is use both. I use the free 2GB in Dropbox for things like you've mentioned, and I purchased the $29 yearly plan for Ubuntu One which gives me 22 GB of storage for most all of my data. The more bugs you can report and more requests to U1, the better it will get!

Comment: Good answer! I will do that. Still, I do wish to see shared (through a URL) photo galleries in Ubuntu ONE.